# Text in html2canvas only displays in one line

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, html2canvas

I'm trying to display text with html2canvas, but when my text is greater than the div width it doesn't cause a line break. Here's the piece of code with my app.

```js
    self.btnLoading = true;

    j.post(php_data.ajaxUrl, ajaxData, function(response) {
      html2canvas([document.getElementById("vhScreen")], {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
          // document.body.appendChild(canvas);
          var data = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
          console.log(data);
          window.open(data);
          // window.location.href = 'data:application/octet-stream;base64,' + data;
        }
      });

      self.btnLoading = false;

      swal({
        title: "Nice Work!",
        text: "Your epic neon is added to your cart!",
        type: "success"
      }, function() {
        window.location = "/cart";
      });
    });
  }
}, 500);
```

Comment: https://prnt.sc/qxxjzk I'm only referring with this code (html2canvas). thank you